# Typescript : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying to setup Angular2 with Typescript and ASP.NET Core. Here is package.json :

```
{
  "name": "testappuit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

and systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'app',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        },
    packages: {
                app: {
                    main: './main.js',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                rxjs: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                    main: './index.js',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
    })(this);
```

and app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and main.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts" />
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app/main').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the project structure:
[image]

if i try to run it in the browser i keep getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   System is not defined

Help me to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because your systemjs.config.js is not at the root of your project, try moving it to the root with your package.json. OR try to map directly to it in your index.html I.E.

```
<script src="app/systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="wwwroot/app/systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

and you may even want to add the higher levels as well. It is also recommended to have your index.html at the root of your project as well. If when you are running your application and you do not see

```
Loading...
```

Then that is a tip off that your project isn't seeing your index.html either.

ps sorry for all the edits

Another issue could be that your project can't find 'app' So try mapping that out as well in your systemjs.config.js for example

```
map: {
        app: 'src/testappUI/wwwroot/app',
```

Comment: `Loading..` is visible on browser. I have ever tried moving `systemjs.config.js` to root also, but still same error

Comment: and you tried just adding "app" in front of your  `<script src="app/systemjs.config.js"></script>` in index.html

Comment: just out of curiosity... in you tsconfig.json why are you exluding node_modules and wwwroot? from my understanding this will remove the .js files from being compiled which will also cause you project to break. try removing those excludes? kind of a shot in the dark there.... I know your problem is that you project isnt seeing your systemjs somehow

Comment: @Vivek try something random for me please, set everything back to how you had it original (like in your question) and just move your main.js in the same folder as you main.ts. and remove those exclude statements from you tsconfig. if this doesnt work... then I would strongly recommend visiting angular.io and just following the quickstart. and follow their folder structure (the final folder structure is shown at the bottom of their quickstart page)